# How to rename lots of files with several dots in them and making them a new suffix with file extension?

Tags: batch-file, rename

Hello I have a problem where ffmpeg produces a filename where it just ads another .mp4
I do not want to change the ffmpeg script as It is a part of another script so I decided that I would rather make another script which its whole purpose would be just to rename these files from `"something_something".mp4.mp4` to `"something_something"_SmallFile.mp4`

Also if I use this code where the script and files are nested in directory like so:
E:\Folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
than the script stops working entirely, but if it is nested just one folder above it starts working again. Strange.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do rename *.txt *.cmd
pause
```

**Note that this is just a test script to test if it works at all.**

My current code is:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /b "%FilesLocation%"') do if %~xa EQU .mp4.mp4 ren "%a" "%~na_SmalFile.mp4"
```

EDIT:
There is code for ffmpeg:

```
SET /A ffmpeg_qv=24

for /R %%A in (*.mp4, *.avi, *.mov, *.wmv, *.ts, *.m2ts, *.mkv, *.mts) do (
    echo Processing "%%A"
    ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i "%%A" -pix_fmt nv12 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map_metadata 0 -c:v h264_amf -gops_per_idr 1 -rc cqp -qp_p %ffmpeg_qv% -qp_i %ffmpeg_qv% -b:v 0K -c:a aac -b:a 384k -movflags +faststart -movflags use_metadata_tags "%%A.mp4"
```

Comment: The problem is probably that the command you're using, which you've not shown us, _(for some inexplicable reason)_ is incorrect. With my mindreading powers, I can see that it should be using the `%%~n` variable expansion. Please do not post code which is not exhibiting an issue, and ask questions about unposted code which is. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64227789/edit) to bring it up to a standard, whereby we can answer it, without guessing.

Comment: Sorry for that I was rushing because I had a lot of things to do. I have added the code into the question.

Comment: Why are you doing a directory listing of everything, when you clearly only need to work with those files which end with `*.mp4.mp4`?

Comment: I am new to a CMD and Batch files, that is why I do not want to edit the ffmpeg script, and I was trying to find a solution on the internet. I am dumb for using this I assume, as it seem that it is absolutely unnecessary.
And to answer your question. I was originaly trying the first command in the question.

Comment: I just tried the most easy command `ren *.mp4.mp4 _SmallFile.mp4` and nothing happend, but if I do use this `ren *.mp4 _SmallFile.mp4` then it works BUT it literally ads _SmallFile.mp4 suffix. It does not remove the previous one as long as there is something before the dot.

Comment: to build a second script to correct an error from a faulty script instead of fixing the faulty script seems ... suboptimal at best.

Comment: `the script stops working entirely, but if it is nested just one folder above it starts working again. Strange.` Not at all. Read the output of `for /?` what the `/d` switch does.

Comment: Yea, I know. So I added the script for the ffmpeg to the question.

Comment: just change in your ffmpeg script to  `... use_metadata_tags "%%~nA.mp4"` (keep the other `%%A`'s)

Comment: …which incidentally, is exactly what I guessed was the issue with it in my opening comment!

Comment: But I want it to end like this: `"something_something"_SmallFile.mp4` not like `"something_something".mp4`

Comment: so `"%%~nA_SmallFile".mp4` ?

Comment: You are a good. Thank you very much. Just want to ask What does the %%~n do? And why if I just left %%A it just adds a suffix?   
Also sorry to booth of you (Compo and Stephan). I was really frustrated, because I need to re-render like 400+ videos and I need it asap.
I do appreciate your effort and help and I am very grateful to booth of you. Thank you!

Comment: read the output of `for /?`, especially the "Modifiers" section. Don't worry, it takes a few minutes to grasp the concept, but it opens a new world of batch coding, once you got it.

Comment: Take a look at this very useful thread: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874)